# Pre-store data from database, or get just necessary?

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux

Let's see, we have an app where the user has projects. They can even create hundreds of projects, and every project can have hundreds of parts, but just can work with one project. I'm setting a live fetch on it with firebase, which looks like this:

```
/*
projectsOfUser = {
  projectOne: {
    // hundreds of attributes
  },
  projectTwo: {
    //hundreds of attributes
  },
  //hundreds of projects (probably not, but it's possible)
}
*/
const listenProjectChanges = () => async dispatch => {
  projectsdb.on("value", snap => {
    const projects = snap.val();

    dispatch({
      type: "PROJECTS_SET",
      projects
    });
  });
};
```

In the above code `projectsdb` can be the container of all projects, or just the current one. If we separate them, so call first, and get the initial data of the current project, and then get the rest project will have obviously a better UX, but I just wanted to show an example what I mean. The question becomes interesting when we're talking about how much projects the user have. If the user has only two projects, we get the advantage that if it changes the current project, the data will be available immediately. I have to think about that all the data will be stored in redux, but as a good point, the data is separated and flattened so if a project gets updated, which is not in use by the current user (which is possible because users share the projects, so another user can edit another project, but the current project as well), it will not cause a re-render.

The main question is: when it's worth for it to get data, which could be used in the future, but maybe not, to make it available immediately? Which has more value? Browser memory, or fetching data?

Answer (score 0):

I would do an initial pass to get the "metadata" so you can do things like generate a list of projects and what not.

If the user experience is to have real-time access to all of their projects you could use a service worker that runs in the background and acquires the necessary bits.